# What is a similar phrase to "scratch that"?

Tags: phrases, idioms, interjections

On Twitter, a reporter tweeted a phrase similar to "scratch that" once he realized he had made a factual error in his original tweet -- I cannot for the life of me remember what that phrase was!

Any suggestions as to what two-word phrase could have the same meaning as "scratch that"?

It wasn't *nix that*, *forget that* or *never mind* - it was something more fancy.

Comment: *Nix that, forget that, never mind*?

Comment: None of the above -- it was something more fancy ;)

Comment: The only other thing I can think of that's related is *mea culpa*. But it doesn't mean "scratch that," it means "my mistake." Do you have any other guidance?

Comment: Not really; though I googled it then, and it meant something like "ignore the last statement I wrote". Now I cannot even find it in my history searches, which is why I am here...

Comment: Was it actually an English phrase?

Comment: Hi Sara, welcome to EL&U. I've edited your question to remove the "thanks" message (thanks, but it's not what we need in a question) and to add your clarification regarding @JasonBassford's suggestions (to prevent these very suggestions being offered as answers, given they're not what you're after). You can [edit] your question at any time to further refine it. For further guidance, see [answer]. And don't forget to take the **[Tour]** of our site - it gives a useful overview of how it all works, and you earn a badge! :-)

Comment: my bad?  (not fancy though!);  belay that?

Comment: Oh, please! Do something to alleviate this annoying itch!

Comment: 'retract'?  'delete'?  'expunge'? ... can you say whether the second word was indeed 'that'?

Comment: Please **disregard** my last post.

Comment: @JasonBassford yes, it was definitely an English phrase!

Comment: None of the above; and I cannot recall if it had "that" in it...

Answer (score 1):

After going through my browser history **again**, turns out the phrase I was looking for is "check that" and it is the *slang* version of "scratch that".